# How to find the differences from 2 ArrayLists of Strings?

Tags: java, arraylist, array-difference

I have 2 Strings:

```
A1=[Rettangolo, Quadrilatero, Rombo, Quadrato]
A2=[Rettangolo, Rettangolo, Rombo, Quadrato]
```

I want to obtain this: "I have found "Quadrilatero", instead of "Rettangolo" ".
If I use `removeAll()` or `retainAll()` it doesn't work because I have 2 instances of "Rettangolo".
In fact, if I use `a1.containsAll(a2)`, I get true and I want false.

Thanks all for considering my request.

Comment: Can arrays differ in length?

Comment: Do you want all the elements in A1 to be present in A2 whatever the order or is the order also important?

Comment: Yes arrays size can be different. The order is not important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) method from ArrayList. It only removes the first occurance.

```
public static void main(String []args){
        //Create ArrayLists
        String[] A1 = {"Rettangolo", "Quadrilatero", "Rombo", "Quadrato"};
        ArrayList<String> a1=new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(A1));
        String[] A2 ={"Rettangolo", "Rettangolo", "Rombo", "Quadrato"};
        ArrayList<String> a2=new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(A2));
        // Check ArrayLists
        System.out.println("a1 = " + a1);
        System.out.println("a2 = " + a2);
        // Find difference
        for( String s : a1)
            a2.remove(s);
        // Check difference
        System.out.println("a1 = " + a1);
        System.out.println("a2 = " + a2);
}
```

**Result**

```
a1 = [Rettangolo, Quadrilatero, Rombo, Quadrato]
a2 = [Rettangolo, Rettangolo, Rombo, Quadrato]
a1 = [Rettangolo, Quadrilatero, Rombo, Quadrato]
a2 = [Rettangolo]
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I will really appreciate it because I tried with remove  method iterating on the 2 lists but I got bad luck.

Comment: switch a1 and a2 in the for each loop to get the other result. Then you can just add them to your output statement.

Comment: Prior to calling `for (String s: a1)`, you could do `if Collections.disjoint(a1, a2) then print a1`. `disjoint` = no elements in common, so print the whole array. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint(java.util.Collection, java.util.Collection)

Comment: I especially liked the a2.remove(s) statement.  I liked the fact that removing an item that isn't present is a no-op.  Very elegant.

Answer (score 2):

These two classes might help. Let me know how I can improve this further. 
Feel free to use the code below in your own work.
I must point out that the current **code does not take care of repeated list elements.**

```
import java.util.List;

public class ListDiff<T> {

    private List<T> removed;
    private List<T> added;

    public ListDiff(List<T> removed, List<T> added) {
        super();
        this.removed = removed;
        this.added = added;
    }

    public ListDiff() {
        super();
    }

    public List<T> getRemoved() {
        return removed;
    }

    public List<T> getAdded() {
        return added;
    }

}
```

Util class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class ListUtil {

    public static <T> ListDiff<T> diff(List<T> one, List<T> two) {

        List<T> removed = new ArrayList<T>();
        List<T> added = new ArrayList<T>();

        for (int i = 0; i < one.size(); i++) {
            T elementOne = one.get(i);
            if (!two.contains(elementOne)) {
                //element in one is removed from two
                removed.add(elementOne);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < two.size(); i++) {
            T elementTwo = two.get(i);
            if (!one.contains(elementTwo)) {
                //element in two is added.
                added.add(elementTwo);
            }
        }

        return new ListDiff<T>(removed, added);
    }

    public static <T> ListDiff<T> diff(List<T> one, List<T> two, Comparator<T> comparator) {
        List<T> removed = new ArrayList<T>();
        List<T> added = new ArrayList<T>();

        for (int i = 0; i < one.size(); i++) {
            T elementOne = one.get(i);
            boolean found = false;

            //loop checks if element in one is found in two.
            for (int j = 0; j < two.size(); j++) {
                T elementTwo = two.get(j);
                if (comparator.compare(elementOne, elementTwo) == 0) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found == false) {
                //element is not found in list two. it is removed.
                removed.add(elementOne);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < two.size(); i++) {
            T elementTwo = two.get(i);
            boolean found = false;

            //loop checks if element in two is found in one.
            for (int j = 0; j < one.size(); j++) {
                T elementOne = one.get(j);
                if (comparator.compare(elementTwo, elementOne) == 0) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found == false) {
                //it means element has been added to list two. 
                added.add(elementTwo);
            }

        }

        return new ListDiff<T>(removed, added);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] arr1 = { "london", "newyork", "delhi", "singapore", "tokyo", "amsterdam" };
        String[] arr2 = { "london", "newyork", "delhi", "singapore", "seoul", "bangalore", "oslo" };

        ListDiff<String> ld = ListUtil.diff(Arrays.asList(arr1), Arrays.asList(arr2));
        System.out.println(ld.getRemoved());
        System.out.println(ld.getAdded());

        ld = ListUtil.diff(Arrays.asList(arr1), Arrays.asList(arr2), new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        }); //sample for using custom comparator
        System.out.println(ld.getRemoved());
        System.out.println(ld.getAdded());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are three solutions.

An implementation that uses a remove method.

```
public static boolean same(List<String> list1, List<String> list2){
    if (list1.size() != list2.size())
        return false;
    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(list1);
    temp.removeAll(list2);
    return temp.size() == 0;
}
```

A solution that sorts then compares.

```
public static boolean same(List<String> list1, List<String> list2){
    if (list1.size() != list2.size())
        return false;
    Collections.sort(list1);
    Collections.sort(list2);
    for (int i=0;i<list1.size();i++){
        if (!list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(i)))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And, just for fun, you could do this by doing a word count difference between the two arrays.  It wouldn't be the most efficient, but it works and possibly could be useful.

```
public static boolean same(List<String> list1, List<String> list2){
    Map<String,Integer> counts = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    for (String str : list1){
        Integer i = counts.get(str);
        if (i==null)
            counts.put(str, 1);
        else
            counts.put(str, i+1);
    }
    for (String str : list2){
        Integer i = counts.get(str);
        if (i==null)
            return false; /// found an element that's not in the other
        else
            counts.put(str, i-1);
    }
    for (Entry<String,Integer> entry : counts.entrySet()){
        if (entry.getValue() != 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will find the intersection between two arrays for this specific case you have explained.

```
String[] A1 = { "Rettangolo", "Quadrilatero", "Rombo", "Quadrato" };
String[] A2 = { "Rettangolo", "Rettangolo", "Rombo", "Quadrato" };
ArrayList<String> a1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(A1));
ArrayList<String> a2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(A2));
a1.removeAll(a2);
System.out.println("I have found " + a1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
    String[] A1 =  {"Rettangolo", "Quadrilatero", "Rombo", "Quadrato"};
    String[] A2 ={"Rettangolo", "Rettangolo", "Rombo", "Quadrato"};

    Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>();

    set1.addAll(Arrays.asList(A1));
    set2.addAll(Arrays.asList(A2));

    set1.removeAll(set2);
    System.out.println(set1);// ==> [Quadrilatero]
```